# Appending list of dates to list of lists removes date format

Tags: r, list, date, mapply

I'm trying to append a list of dates to a list of lists such as `myList` below. This is working as expected except the date format for the date element in each list element is lost. Any ideas?

```
myList<-list(list("event"="A"),
             list("event"="B"),
             list("event"="C"))

dates<-as.Date(c("2011-06-05","2012-01-12","2016-05-09"))

outList<-mapply(FUN="c",myList,eventDate=as.list(dates),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I'm looking to achieve the below

```
[[1]]
  [[1]]$event
  [1] "A"

  [[1]]$eventDate
  [1] "2011-06-05"


[[2]]
  [[2]]$event
  [1] "B"

  [[2]]$eventDate
  [1] "2012-01-12"


[[3]]
  [[3]]$event
  [1] "C"

  [[3]]$eventDate
  [1] "2016-06-09"
```

Comment: Interesting, could someone maybe explain why this behavior happens? I would have expected a character instead of a numeric since the documentation of `c` states 'All arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the returned value'. Where is the flaw in my line of thought?

Comment: FYI, `mapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` is the same as `Map(...)`

Comment: Dates are usually stored as integers (days since "origin", usually 1970-01-01, 1900-01-01, or other weirder days if you go into Excel/Mac...).
Thus `c` decides the lowest common type is a numeric and not a character (saves space this way). Does that make sense @Florian

Comment: Good suggestion `Map` is considerably faster as well @Sotos

Comment: @David, Thanks for the explanation, I missed the fact that myList was a list of lists, rather than a list of characters. So `c(unlist(myList)[[1]],as.list(dates)[[1]])` works as I expected. Although I would not have guessed that the lowest common type between a list and a Date is numeric? e.g. `c(myList[[1]],as.list(dates)[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks  for this insight @David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Map`, you can also create a small (lambda) function like so:

```r
myList <- list(
  list(event = "A"),
  list(event = "B"),
  list(event = "C")
)

dates <- as.Date(c("2011-06-05", "2012-01-12", "2016-05-09"))

outList <- Map(f = function(origList, date) {
  origList$eventDate <- date
  return(origList)
}, myList, dates)

outList
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$event
#> [1] "A"
#> 
#> [[1]]$eventDate
#> [1] "2011-06-05"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$event
#> [1] "B"
#> 
#> [[2]]$eventDate
#> [1] "2012-01-12"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]]$event
#> [1] "C"
#> 
#> [[3]]$eventDate
#> [1] "2016-05-09"
```

The reason why you get the dates converted to numbers, is that the `c` function converts all elements to the lowest common type (usually characters, in this case numeric).

For example:

```r
c(123, as.Date("2016-01-01"))
#> [1]   123 16801
```

Comment: All good answers, however using Map instead of mapply in the above way is the fastest way of executing this so this takes the cream.

Answer (score 4):

It may be better to index as `c` could coerce it to integer storage value

```
for(i in seq_along(myList)) myList[[i]][['eventDate']] <- dates[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

An additional list wrapper to insulate each Date element will also work here. I constructed that by running an `lapply` with the `list` function on the dates vector:

```
Map("c", myList, eventDate=lapply(dates, list))
[[1]]
[[1]]$event
[1] "A"

[[1]]$eventDate
[1] "2011-06-05"


[[2]]
[[2]]$event
[1] "B"

[[2]]$eventDate
[1] "2012-01-12"


[[3]]
[[3]]$event
[1] "C"

[[3]]$eventDate
[1] "2016-05-09"
```